# Similarity score between two detected images

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, similarity

I am currently implementing a detection and tracking system by tracking heads. I was trying to figure out some similarity score between two detected images so that I can analyse if the detections are of the same person or not (in different frames).  I tried to change the RGB images (detections) into HSV and concatenate the Hue and Saturation values into one single vector for each image. Then I found the difference between the vectors of the separate detections by using the summation of the absolute difference.

However, when I tried it, a detection of a bag had a better similarity score than that of the same head.  Can someone guide me with what maybe is wrong or else any better comparison technique?

Comment: An [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be good. otherwise I think this question is too broad.

Comment: if you are trying to achieve face recognition (which I think you do) comparing HSV values is not the way to go. Look online for face recognition algorithms. The simplest would probably be Eigen Faces, but there are many others

Comment: I am actually doing Head detection comparison...I posted a new question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723670/intersection-over-union-between-two-detections)